# JMS Class Path JAR Upgrade

Tags: activemq-classic

After upgrading the JARs in the class path for WebSphere is not connecting to ActiveMQ Classic.

Previous JARs:

- activemq-client-5.14.5.jar
- hawtbuf-1.11.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar

Updated JARs:

- activemq-client-5.17.6.jar
- hawtbuf-1.11.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar

Are there any additional JARs that need to be added, or do I need to change the external initial context factory? My current External Initial Context Factory:

```
org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
```

error received in WAS

```
ERROR com.temenos.t24browser.servlets.FormFieldInputFilter - java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE199E bad major version 55.0 of class=org/apache/activemq/jndi/ActiveMQInitialContextFactory, the maximum supported major version is 52.0&#59; offset=6 –
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveMQ v5.16.7 is available with JDK 8 support. This includes the fix for the security vulnerability (CVE-2023-46604).

ref: https://activemq.apache.org/activemq-5016007-release

Comment: Thanks for the command yes currently using ActiveMQ v5.16.0 in my production

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ Classic 5.17.6 requires at least Java **11**. Based on the error message it appears you're using Java 8 instead. You need to upgrade your Java version before you can use the upgraded jar files.